# Why is the success rate low and yet still better than random guessing?

Tags: logistic, k-nearest-neighbour

I'm reading Introduction to Statistical Learning. It mentions on page 166 for KNN modeling that a success rate of 11.7% is more than double that of random guessing. My question is, first what is the success rate of random guessing and why is the success rate for KNN so low and yet better than other success rates like that of logistic regression which is around 50%?

Answer (score 2):

Your question is difficult to understand without the context. It is about using the `Caravan` data set to predict purchasers of caravan insurance

What the book says is that using KNN with $K=1$ gives the following results

```
> table(knn.pred,test.Y)
           test.Y
knn.pred   No  Yes
No        873   50
Yes        68    9
```

which means that, after basing the model on $4882$ individuals in the training set and applying that model to the $1000$ other individuals in the test set, it predicts $68+9=77$ people will purchase insurance, and it gets $9$ of these correct, a proportion $\frac9{77}=11.7\%$ correct

If it had been guessing insurance purchasers at random, it would have got an expected proportion $\frac{59}{1000}=5.9\%$ of those predicted to buy correct, about half the KNN figure.  So it says KNN did better than random guessing

It goes on to say using KNN with $K=3$ would have led to $\frac{5}{26}=19.2\%$ while using $K=5$ would have led to $\frac{4}{15}=26.7\%$ correct

It does not say that with the same problem  logistic regression would have a success rate of around $50\%$.  Rather the opposite:

> As a comparison, we can also fit a logistic regression model to the data.
>   If we use $0.5$ as the predicted probability cut-off for the classifier, then
>   we have a problem: only seven of the test observations are predicted to
>   purchase insurance. Even worse, we are wrong about all of these!
>
> However, we are not required to use a cut-off of $0.5$. If we instead predict a purchase any time the predicted probability of purchase exceeds $0.25$, we get much better results: we predict that $33$ people will purchase insurance, and we are correct for about $33\%$ of these people. This is over five times better than random guessing!

The moral of the story illustrated by this part of the book is that some questions are difficult, but with suitable methods and good parameters, some machine learning can still produce results which are substantially better than random guessing

Comment: Thank you very much, Henry! Your answer was detailed and helpful.

Comment: Hi Henry, I have one more question for you. How exactly do you figure 59 for random guessing? I assume it's from the confusion matrix (50 + 9)...

Comment: @user2342434242 Yes. $50+9$ is the number of actual insurance purchases in the $1000$ element test set

Comment: Hey Henry, still a little confused... why choose 50, isn't that a false-positive? And by the same token, why choose 68?

Comment: @user2342434242: $77$ is the number predicted positive for the test set using KNN and $K=1$: of these $9$ were *true positives* and $68$ were *false positives*, giving a *precision* of $\frac{9}{77}$.  Meanwhile $59$ was the number of actual cases: of these $9$ were predicted positive, so *true positives*, and $50$ were predicted negative so *false negatives*, giving a *sensitivity* of $\frac{9}{59}$.  There were $873$ *true negatives*

Comment: But isn't 68 a false-negative? I'm looking at the confusion matrix in my book and the bottom left corner is for false-negatives. And the top-right is for false-positives. What am I missing?

Comment: @user2342434242 The labels in a table are more important than the physical location: I suspect that you are looking at the table layout on page 148 but this is transposed from the tables on pages 145, 146, 158, 159, 160, 162, 164, 166, 167

Comment: I'm still confused. What do you mean by "The labels are more important than the physical location"? I am looking at the table on 148. Is 68 not a false-negative?

Comment: @user2342434242: The table on page 148 has "True class" on the left, talking about the rows, and "Predicted class" on the top talking about the columns.  The table at the bottom of page 166 has "knn.pred" on the left and "Test.Y" at the top, i.e. has the labels transposed, and similarly with all the other tables.  Meanwhile [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confusion_matrix#Table_of_confusion) has yet another layout, with true positives in the top left rather than the bottom right cell.  So you need to read the labels in each case to understand what is being said

Comment: thank you so much for explaining that to me. Much appreciated!

Comment: Hey Henry, I have one more question for you! Why do we choose 50 and 9 for random guessing? What role do they play in comparison to the confusion matrix?

Comment: I know you mention 9 were predicted positive and 50 were predicted negative so they are false negatives, but how does this equate to random guessing. I suppose, what is the definition of random guessing?

Comment: If $59$ out of $1000$ individuals are actually buying insurance, then if you select $N$ individuals at random and predict they are buying insurance, the expected number of correct predictions is $\dfrac{59}{1000}N$